# Updated 12.04 and now Xorg is dead from NVidia drivers

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, command-line, xorg

I updated (August 16) Ubuntu 12.04 today and while I admit I didn't look what was being updated, it was large enough to have had an NVidia update in it. Problem is later on when I turned on my laptop again it won't boot into a GUI, just to the terminal (which I don't really know much of how to do anything). Now I have been able to log in and type "startx" to start up the GUI and now its complaining that my NVidia driver (if I remember correctly) is listed as being version 304.(number) and the version installed/found is version 295.(number). I don't know how this happened and now I'm stuck. I have no idea how it happened and don't know how to fix.

Does anyone have any ideas? I have only access to wifi internet and no idea how to log on without the GUI so getting a new NVidia package isn't something I would know how to do even... Any and all help would be highly appreciated.

edit: If it helps, I'm using a ASUS G Series G53JW-A1 http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834220861

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get the 304 version of the driver is to download it from Nvidia's website, and then do a manual install. Now, the options are: 1.reinstall the 304 driver, or 2.remove it and use the one provided by Ubuntu.

1) To remove everything Nvidia related from the repositories, run

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

... then run the manual installer you've downloaded from Nvidia.

2) To uninstall the manually installed driver, use the downloaded installer to run

```
sudo sh NVIDIA* --uninstall
```

...then

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

...then reboot, and if you get the GUI, use the Additional Drivers utility. If not, run

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Comment: I don't know how to do that though from the terminal and a wireless internet only. I've tried looking up how to log onto a wireless from the terminal with no avail and I have tried to figure out how to mount either another (Windows) partition or USB and still can't. While its great you have made a nice and clear answer that I should be able to follow easily, I am still stuck either downloading and copying the file over from Windows or even just using apt-get with a wireless connection, neither is something I can do at the moment. I would prefer the internet option since apt-get is easy for me